# Can we infer generic output type?

Tags: scala

Consider the following Scala code

```
def NOTImplementedIn[T<: AnyRef](t:T):String = 
  throw new Exception(t.getClass.getName+": Input type not implemented")

def NOTImplementedOut[T<: AnyRef](s:String):T = 
  throw new Exception("Output type not implemented")
```

In the first case, it is possible to infer the input type `T`. Is there any way to infer the output type `T` in the second case? I would like to include the type name in the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using a [`Manifest`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/reflect/Manifest.html).

```
def NOTImplementedOut[T<: AnyRef](s:String)(implicit m: scala.reflect.Manifest[T]):T =
  throw new Exception(m.toString + ": Output type not implemented")
```

Answer (score 5):

The lower type bound of `T` will always be inferred. If no lower type bound is explicitly given, Nothing is the bound.

This inference is the correct one. As generic parameter type are erased as run time, calls to `f[String]("foo")`, `f[File]("foo")` and `f[List[Int]]("foo")` and `f[Nothing]("foo")` are the same call `f("foo")` at run time. The result must be a valid `String`, `File`, `List[Int]`, and `Nothing`. Being `Nothing` is the only way to satisfy that (which means there will be no result). If there was a stronger lower type bound, it would only need to be of that type.

A consequence of that is that a routine `f[T >: LowerBound](parameters): T,` where `T` does not appears in the `parameters`, is no different from `f(parameters): LowerBound`, and there is no point in making it generic (when `LowerBound` is not explicitly stated, the bound is type `Nothing`)

With the same idea that the call `f[T]("foo")` is only `f("foo")` at runtime, it is clear that the name of cannot appear in the exception message. So `T` has to be someway passed at runtime, and manifests are the normal way to do that, as noted by Dave. Now, `T` does appear in the parameters, and everything is different. if one calls `f[File]("foo")`, the compiler will transform that to `f("foo")(manifest_of_file)` where `manifest_of_file` allows among other thing to get the name  of the type File.

This is still not inference, as `File` has been explicitly written. The only way type `T` can be inferred is from the expected type of the call to `f` in context. If one does `val file: File = f("foo")`, or passes `f("foo")` the value of a parameter of type File to some routine, or simply writes `f("foo"): File`,  will `File` be inferred? No, it won't. Once again, `Nothing` will be inferred. The reason is that it is a more precise type than File, and as the compiler can pass either a Manifest[File] or a Manifest[Nothing] (and any type in between) it choose the more precise one. This may be surprising for `Nothing`, but suppose that your lower type bound is `String`, and the expected type is simply `AnyRef`, there is no obvious reason to chose AnyRef rather than the better String.

```
def f[T >: String : Manifest](s: String): T = "type is " + manifest[T].toString
val x: AnyRef = f("foo"): AnyRef
x: Anyref = type is java.lang.String
```

Same with your example and `Nothing` as the lower type bound:

```
def g[T: Manifest](s: String): T = throw new Exception("type is " + manifest[T])
val y: String  = g("foo"): String
java.lang.Exception: type is Nothing
        at .g(<console>:7)
        ....
```